# Considering a list a=["boo",[1,2,3]], why does print(a[0:2][0:1]) prints ['boo'] whereas print(a[0:2][0:2]) prints ['boo',[1,2,3]]?

Tags: python, list, slice

if `print(a[0:2][0:2])` prints `['boo',[1,2,3]]`?
Shouldn't `print(a[0:2][0:1])` print `[ 'boo' , [1,2]]`?

Comment: You should read about Python's indexing mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that list slicing in Python works is the following:
When you're executing `a[0:2][0:1]` on list `a=[“boo”,[1,2,3]]`, first the `a[0:2]` gets executed, which gives you as a result list with elements from position 0 to 1
=> `[“boo”,[1,2,3]]`.
Next the `[0:1]` gets executed on that result, and it returns list with just the element on 0 position, which is `[“boo”]`.

When executing `a[0:2][0:2]` on list `a=[“boo”,[1,2,3]]`, first you get the elements on positions 0 and 1 => `[“boo”,[1,2,3]]`, and then you ask again for elements on positions 0 and 1 (`[0:2]`), and that's exactly `[“boo”,[1,2,3]]`.

Answer (score 0):

here `a[0:2]` tells all the element in index range [1,2)  so this will create a sublist

```
sublist = ['boo', [1, 2, 3]]
```

and

`a[0:2][0:1]` this tell that in the sublist again a sublist having element index range form [0,1) ie `['boo']` .

Answer (score 0):

If you unnest your indexing operations it might help to see why:

```
a = ['boo', [1, 2, 3]] 
b = a[0:2] # this creates a new list from `a` with elements 0 and 1
b[0] # 'boo'
b[1] # [1, 2, 3]
f = b[0:1] # before this, b is the same as ['boo', [1, 2, 3]]
           # retrieving only the first element [0, 1], returns a new list:
f[0] # 'boo'
f # ['foo'] (a list with just 'foo')
```

While creating a list with the same content as the list in front of it (`[0:2]`) gives a different result:

```
c = a[0:2] # this creates a new list from `a` with elements 0 and 1
c[0] # 'boo'
c[1] # [1, 2, 3]
c[0:2] # the same as a[0:2][0:2], which is the same as just `c` as well.
```

`a` and `c` contains the same data in this case.